# REST service and scheduled message sending

Tags: java, rest, email, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a client-server application using Jersey as JAX-RS implementation. I use the code below for handling user requests.

```
@Path("service")
public class SomeRestService {

    @POST
    @Path("good")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Resp getCardRequest(Req request) {
        String result = "Request has been received: " + request;
        Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

                // Here it becomes clear that the service will have to send an email to someone@mail.com with some content on 17.01.2019 at 14:00 for example
                ...

             Resp response = ...

       return response;
    }
```

As far as I know every user request triggers a creation of thread on server side. After the response has been returned, the thread terminates. So If I have to send an email to the customer in a month or at specific date and time, I have to schedule it somehow. I thought about storing the required information in the database and run unix utilities like `cron`, or `at` to query the corresponding tables and send emails if needed. Not sure whether it's the best way for doing such a task. How is it done usually? I was told that in the future there may be other notification channels like sms, whatsapp, viber etc.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad and answers also might be opinion based. But anyway if you need to do some recurring email tasks - like days/weeks after the request - persisting the information somewhere else that memory/thread is wise :) . Also I think that the future channels are as well supported in Java as for example by doing some -say- bash script and the decision what to use is dependent on the situation. My advice is that just try to think & make the persistence implementation "abstract" in sense that it does not hinder using any method/library & for mailing later.

Comment: @pirho I just don't want to reinvent the wheel. I have a feeling that lots of web applications face it. You constantly receive emails about password expiration, birthday wishes from various websites where you have an account etc. They must somehow store the needed information and send it when the time comes. I just asked about the approach or some key steps in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One option that I've used in the past was Quartz Framework.

I would give a read to the [CronTrigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html).

For example you define a JOB:

```
public class SimpleJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        // send email code
    }
}
```

And you write code to trigger it  every Friday at noon or every weekday at 9:30 am:

```
CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
  .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
  .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/2 8-17 * * ?"))
  .forJob("myJob", "group1")
  .build();
```